# UK Visitor Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, ghanaian-citizens

I am a student currently studying in Hungary and will like to visit a family friend in the UK for the summer holidays for a period of 2 weeks.

The documents I will be providing are:

I) My uncles Bank Statements
II) Permission letter from School
III) Bank statements and sponsorship letter from my uncle
IV) Translated Letters
V) Residence Permit and Passport

Is there anything I will need?

Comment: Are you under 18?

Comment: What is your citizenship, and is it Summer 2020 or 2021 you intend to visit? EU citizens can visit the UK visa-free until 31 Dec 2020 - until the end of the EU withdrawal transition.

Comment: I'm over 18, and I am not an EU citizen. I am a ghanaian, currently holding a residence permit

Answer (score 1):

Going through the [UK visa supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) and seeing what you must prove, I noticed you proved:

- You have funds available (with the bank statements and sponsorship letter)
- Confirmation of legal residence (Residence Permit and Passport)
- You have permission to be out of school

Additionally, if you are under 18 and traveling alone, you should provide:

> - under 18s – we strongly recommend you submit the following information otherwise it may delay consideration of your application
>
>   - a Birth Certificate or legal document (such as adoption papers) showing the relationship between you and your parent or guardian
>   - if travelling unaccompanied or with someone other than your parent or guardian you should provide:
>
>     - a signed letter from your parent(s) confirming details of anyone accompanying you, and details of care and accommodation
>       arranged in the UK
>     - a copy of your parent(s) or legal guardian’s biographical page of their passport, which includes their signature and passport number
>       if your parent(s) do not have a passport then you must provide another
>       official document which bears their signature

Comment: I would recommend that, as well as the uncle’s bank statements, the OP also submits their own https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab and that the uncle submits evidence of the source of the financial support being provided eg pay slips, latest tax return. If the uncle is in the UK but is not a British citizen, he should also submit evidence of his immigration status to satisfy V4.3(b) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: Daniil. Are you implying that I submit my Bank statements as well? 

My uncle is not in the UK.

I don't have enough funds available, that is why my uncle is sponsoring my trip.